# Why react.js event delegation is fast?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading the react documentation of Facebook on github.io. It is written here that react's event delegation is faster than native javascript's event delegation because of some mapping. I want to know how event delegation is faster than the vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Can you link to the exact page where this is written?

Comment: I think he talks about this : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation

Comment: The documentation contains a link to another article that explains why event delegation is fast. Didn't you read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React article (docs) here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation)

According to what i read ... the article explains simply, that React **doesn't attach an event listener for every created item** (because use vanilla js event delegation). "When React starts up, it starts listening for all events at the top level using a single event listener".

That's supposed to be why react delegation is fast.

[I don't think it's necessary to explain how does the event delegation works as you can read how it works here](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).